# Assume that $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in [0,\pi/2]$, and $\sin\alpha+\sin\gamma=\sin\beta$, $\cos\beta+\cos\gamma=\cos\alpha$. Find $\alpha-\beta$.

Tags: trigonometry

> Assume that $\{\alpha, \beta, \gamma\} \subset \left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$, $\sin\alpha+\sin\gamma=\sin\beta$ and $\cos\beta+\cos\gamma=\cos\alpha$.
>
> Try to find a value of $\alpha-\beta$.

Actually I have gotten that $\alpha+2\gamma+\beta=\pi$ and $\sin2\alpha+\sin2\beta=\sin(\alpha+\beta)$, $\cos2\alpha+\cos2\beta=\cos(\alpha+\beta)$

But I can't get further more.

Comment: I fixed the MathJax for the functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\sin 2\alpha+\sin2\beta=\sin(\alpha+\beta)$$
and
$$\cos2\alpha+\cos2\beta=\cos(\alpha+\beta)$$
So by squaring and then adding the above equations, we get
$$(\sin2\alpha+\sin2\beta)^2+(\cos2\alpha+\cos2\beta)^2=\sin^2(\alpha+\beta)+\cos^2(\alpha+\beta)$$
$$\Rightarrow \sin^22\alpha+\sin^22\beta+2\sin2\alpha\sin2\beta+\cos^22\alpha+\cos^22\beta+2\cos2\alpha\cos2\beta=1$$
$$\Rightarrow2\sin2\alpha\sin2\beta+2\cos2\alpha\cos2\beta+2=1$$
$$\Rightarrow\sin2\alpha\sin2\beta+\cos2\alpha\cos2\beta=-\frac12$$
Now we know that $\cos x\cos y+\sin x\sin y=\cos(x-y)$. So
$$\cos(2\alpha-2\beta)=-\frac12$$
$$\Rightarrow2\alpha-2\beta=\frac{2\pi}{3}$$
$$\alpha -\beta=\frac\pi3\ rad=60^\circ$$

Answer (score 3):

we have $$\sin(\gamma)=\sin(\beta)-\sin(\alpha)$$ and $$\cos(\gamma)=\cos(\alpha)-\cos(\beta)$$
squaring and adding both we get
$$-1=-2(\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)+\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta))$$ therefore we obtain
$$\cos(\alpha-\beta)=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: So it looks like that the describe of the problem is not right.

Comment: why that? you can compute $$\alpha-\beta$$ now from the last line

Comment: But 2\pi/3 is larger than \pi/2

Comment: on moment i will look at my calculations

Comment: sorry i forgot the minus sign

Answer (score 1):

$$1=\sin^2\gamma+\cos^2\gamma=(\sin\beta-\sin\alpha)^2+(\cos\alpha-\cos\beta)^2=2-2\cos(\alpha-\beta).$$
Thus, $$\cos(\alpha-\beta)=\frac{1}{2}.$$
In another hand, $$\sin\gamma=\sin\beta-\sin\alpha\geq0,$$
which says $\beta\geq\alpha.$

Id est, $\alpha-\beta=-60^{\circ}$ and we are done!

Comment: @Intoks Liobein Why did you accepted a wrong solution? Maybe have you a question about my solution? I am ready to explain.

Answer (score -1):

If you have $$\sin2\alpha+\sin2\beta=\sin(\alpha+\beta)   \to 2\sin(\alpha+\beta)\sin(\alpha-\beta)=\sin(\alpha+\beta)$$and $$\cos2\alpha+\cos2\beta=\cos(\alpha+\beta)\to \cos(\alpha+\beta)\cos(\alpha-\beta)=\cos(\alpha+\beta) $$divide them 
$$\frac{2\sin(\alpha+\beta)\sin(\alpha-\beta)}{2\cos(\alpha+\beta)\cos(\alpha-\beta)}=\frac{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}{\cos(\alpha+\beta)}\\\to \tan(\alpha-\beta)=1 \to \alpha-\beta=\frac{\pi}{4}$$